# How to develop ROS camera driver?

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, camera-drivers, camera-driver

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am new to  driver development.

So, what are the basic requirements to develop ROS camera driver?

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/283225/how-to-develop-ros-camera-driver?/) by [SumitP](https://answers.ros.org/users/32308/sumitp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-02-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The bare minimum is to get images from your camera and then publish them as sensor_msgs/Image.

OpenCV is good as a data intermediate format, if you can get images from your camera and display them with cv::imshow or save them to disk with imwrite and they look good then converting them to ros with cv_bridge should be painless.

The next thing to do is use image_transport CameraPublisher and use a CameraInfoManager along with it and you will be able to get compressed image outputs and synchronized camera_info messages along with the standard image.

For performance it is good to have the driver be a nodelet.

Dynamic reconfigure support is nice for changing parameters that should be adjustable live- exposure, frame rate, and anything else the camera supports.

Beyond that look at examples of existing cameras:

https://github.com/ros-drivers/usb_cam

https://github.com/magazino/pylon_camera

https://github.com/ros-drivers/pointgrey_camera_driver

https://github.com/ros-drivers/axis_camera

(Is there a generic network or security camera driver?)

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2018-02-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SumitP](https://answers.ros.org/users/32308/sumitp/) on 2018-02-20**:
@lucasw thank you for your information. For Point grey camera Blackfly S (Spinnaker SDK).

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2018-02-20**:
Is that not supported by the existing pointgrey drivers?  If it is only a small set of changes on the existing drivers you should try to fork and make required changes then pull request the changes so that others can use it.

**Comment by [SumitP](https://answers.ros.org/users/32308/sumitp/) on 2018-02-20**:
No. Existing Point Grey camera driver is using Flycapture 2 SDK but I need to use Spinnaker SDK since Blackfly S won't support Flycapture 2.

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2018-02-20**:
Doesn't look like much has happened: https://github.com/ros-drivers/pointgrey_camera_driver/issues/118

camera_aravis looks like it has been forked like crazy which makes it hard to use, but maybe a generic genicam interface work with the Blackfly S?